Angular radio button unchecks other controls on select
Using Angular 17 and reactive form.
There are two controls in the form group and both are radio buttons.
However, when one control is changed, it clears the other controls. However, the value is valid in all controls.
Here is a Stackbliz link with the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-radio-buttons-demo-reactive-forms-f3tiep?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Don't know why or where to find this in the docs...
However, you need to set a "name" attribute on the radio buttons to distinguish the radio groups.
Changes to your stackblitz:
<input id="male"   name="g1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="male" [formControl]="f['gender']">
<input id="female" name="g1" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="female" [formControl]="f['gender']">
<input id="male1"   name="g2" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="male1" [formControl]="f['a']">
<input id="female1" name="g2" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="female1" [formControl]="f['a']">


Adding name worked. Thanks!

Note that this is just a workaround. You should use the angular way to reference inputs in a form group to be save for future updates. Here is the documentation: https://angular.dev/guide/forms/reactive-forms#associate-the-formgroup-model-and-view

To make this clean you should use formContolName instead of passing the whole formControl into the inputs.
Use it like this:
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="male" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="male" formControlName="gender">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="male">Male</label>
            </div>

            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="female" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" value="female" formControlName="gender">
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="female">Female</label>
            </div>

With this you don't need extra name properties and fully leverage the Angular reactive forms.
Documentation for this can be found here: https://angular.dev/guide/forms/reactive-forms#associate-the-formgroup-model-and-view

What if the input is in a child component but form group is in the parent component?

In this case you should consider implementing the ControlValueAccessor interface (lots of guides are in the www).
